# How to move one word right/left in linux/bash?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

**Edit** - please see the same question on [Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10806/how-to-change-previous-next-word-shortcut-in-bash/10809#10809).

What is the equivalent of Windows' CTRL-Right and CTRL-Left ?

Comment: Should this be moved to unix.stackexchange.com? See also this dup - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10806/how-to-change-previous-next-word-shortcut-in-bash/10809#10809

Comment: rather than move it to Unix.SE and have it closed as a dupe there, I just closed it here...Seems like you got your answer so hope that works...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> moves forward, and
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> moves backwards.

But that's not all!

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> moves to the beginning of the line,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> moves to the end of the line,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> performs an interactive history search, which is very useful.

For many more keybindings, comb your way through [`man bash`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html).

Answer (score 11):

Add these two lines to your `~/.inputrc` file:

```
"\eOC": forward-word
"\eOD": backward-word
```

and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> to reread the file to make the changes active in your current session.

You will be able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> to move right or left word by word.

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks, I meant to include that but forgot.

Comment: Very nice, +1. Not accepted, as this is not as scalable for me because I have many different computers and work and don't feel like changing my user preferences on all of them. But very nice nonetheless.